# Schwarz's Triangle Problem Motivation and Applications

Tags: geometry

I was wondering if anyone knows any details about the Schwarz's Triangle Problem, which is also commonly known as Fagnano's Problem.

Specifically, I was wondering what the motivation was to solving the problem?
Or if it has any interesting applications that can be used for other problems?

I have been able to find alot of proofs for the problem just can't find any resources on other details about the problem.

Thanks for the help

Comment: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fagnano%27s_problem). Motivation ? IMOH, as almost all general triangles results, for aesthetical reasons, and not for physical applications. Application: I vaguely remember it is an ingredient in some proofs.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I believe your right. I don't think there was much motivation behind it. Do you by chance remember what proofs those would be?

Comment: I shall try to remember ! The orthic triangle (it is its most current name) has some connections with the important configuration called "Johnson's circles" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthocentric_system#The_common_orthic_triangle.2C_its_incenter_and_excenters)

Comment: Thank-you! Ill look into it